# How the select the last record from a time series in Cassandra?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I want to store some encoded 'data' into cassadra, versioned by timestamp. My tentative schema  is:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id varchar,
  timestamp timestamp,
  data blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id, timestamp)
);
```

I would like to be able to return the list of items, returning only the latest ( highest timestamp) for each item_id; Is it possible with this schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to express such a query in a single CQL statement for this table, so the answer is no.

You can try creating another table, e.g. `latest_items`, and only storing the last update there, so the schema would be:

```
CREATE TABLE latest_items (
  item_id varchar,
  timestamp timestamp,
  data blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
```

If your rows are inserted in timestamp order, the table would naturally contain only the latest row for each item.  Then you can just run `select * from latest_items limit 10000000;`.  This will of course be expensive, because you're fetching all rows, but given your requirements where you actually want all of them, there is no way to avoid it.

This second table involves duplicating your data, but this is a common theme with Cassandra.  You can avoid duplicating the blob by storing it indirectly, i.e. as a path or URL or somesuch.